# Auto selection of Gamma value for image brightness

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, brightness

I have a sequence of images or live video and I want to check if the image is darker or brighter, then adjust the brightness using gamma correction i.e. Image ^ gamma. gamma = 1 do nothing and smaller than 1  value of gamma, bright the image and greater than 1 makes it dark. I have to give the gamma value manual for different types of images or videos.

Code is as follow

```
lookUpTable = np.empty((1,256), np.uint8)
for i in range(256):
    lookUpTable[0,i] = np.clip(pow(i / 255.0, gamma) * 255.0, 0, 255)
res = cv2.LUT(image, lookUpTable)
```

I want to find gamma value automatically checking the image. I tried to find gamma value to brightness using histogram but it seems not good.

Whole Code is as follow

```
        histr = cv2.calcHist([image],[0],None,[256],[0,256]) 
            
    totalPixels = image.shape[0]*image.shape[1]

    maxInd = np.argmax(histr) 
    maxVal = histr[maxInd]
    indP= int(0 if maxInd-5 < 0 else maxInd-5)
    indexN = int(maxVal+5)
    percentAtDark = (maxVal / totalPixels )*100
    darkSum = np.sum(histr[indP:indexN])
    percentDark = (darkSum / totalPixels )*100
    
    if (percentDark > dartThreshold) and (maxInd < 127): 
        gammaList = np.arange(0.01,0.9,0.02)
        gamma=gammaList[maxInd]
    else:
        gamma = 1
   
    lookUpTable = np.empty((1,256), np.uint8)
    for i in range(256):
        lookUpTable[0,i] = np.clip(pow(i / 255.0, gamma) * 255.0, 0, 255)
    res = cv2.LUT(image, lookUpTable)
```

dartThreshold can be set 60 or 70.

For gamma correction you can look at the end of [this page](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc1/tutorial_basic_linear_transform.html)

Can anyone suggest any better method or improvement in this code? Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting no answer, I tried and find something to share. May be I was not able to ask question clearly. I computed the gamma in the following way

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hue, sat, val = cv2.split(hsv)

mid = 0.5
mean = np.mean(val)
meanLog = math.log(mean)
midLog = math.log(mid*255)
gamma =midLog/meanLog
gamma = 1 / gamma
```

and applied it to the original BGR image

```
lookUpTable = np.empty((1,256), np.uint8)
for i in range(256):
    lookUpTable[0,i] = np.clip(pow(i / 255.0, gamma) * 255.0, 0, 255)
res = cv2.LUT(image, lookUpTable)
```

If we change the from `mid = 0.5` to `mid = 1`, gamma value changes by `0.1` i.e. for `mid = 0.5` if we get `0.69` then for `mid = 1`, we will get `gamma = 0.59`.

Comments are most welcome.